# How to test if a Java iterator always uses the same order (reproducible ordering)?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, set

I have a code in which for-each-loops on a Set need to rely on the fact that the iterator returns the elements always in the same order, e.g.

`for(ParameterObject parameter : parameters) {
  /* ... */
}`

The iterators returned by `HashSet` are not guaranteed to have this property, however it is documented that the iterators of `LinkedHashSet` do have this property. So my code uses a `LinkedHashSet` and everything works fine.

However, I am wondering if I could endow the my code with a check that the set passed to it conforms to the requirement. It appears as if this is not possible (except of a direct test on `LinkedHashSet`). There is no interface implemented by `LinkedHashSet` which I could test on and there is no interface implemented by `LinkedHashSet.iterator()` which I could test on. It would be nice if there is an interface like `OrderConsistentCollection` or `OrderConsistentIterator`.

(I need this property [here](http://svn.finmath.net/finmath%20lib/trunk/src/main/java/net/finmath/marketdata/calibration/ParameterAggregation.java)).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to check this property either at compile- or at runtime.

Comment: Apart from using `instanceof` to test the Set implementation, I don't see... The question however is, why do you want that?

Comment: If you want to maintain order of inserted entries, use a `List`. If you want to maintain the *natural* order of entries, use a `SortedSet`.

Comment: Have you considered implementing your own interface, even if it is only a "marker" interface (ie no methods)?

Comment: It is indeed only a "marker" interface. The reason why I need this is the following: My class has a getter which iterates through a set and combines properties of the objects in the sets to a single property, which it returns. It also has a setter which un-combines the arguments, iterates through the set and assigns the sub-properties to the elements. The order of combination is irrelevant for the problem, however, in order to have this work getter and setter have to use always the same iteration order.

Comment: The only test is to read the Javadoc ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way you can check for it -- but you can ensure it anyway, by simply copying the set into a collection that does have that property. A `LinkedHashSet` would do the trick, but if all you need is the iteration, an `ArrayList` would probably serve you better.

```
List<Foo> parameters = new ArrayList<>(parametersSet);
```

Now `parameters` will always return an iterator with the same ordering.

That said, you'd probably be fine with Evgeniy Dorofeev's suggestion, which points out that even the sets that don't guarantee a particular ordering usually *do* have a stable ordering (even if they don't guarantee it). `HashSet` acts that way, for instance. You'd actually have to have a pretty funky set, or take active randomization measures, to not have a stable ordering.

`HashSet`'s ordering is not guaranteed, but it depends on the hash codes of its elements as well as the order in which they were inserted; they don't want to guarantee anything because they don't want to lock themselves into any one strategy, and even this loose of a contract would make for essentially random order if the objects' hash codes came from `Object.hashCode()`. Rather than specifying an ordering with complex implications, and then saying it's subject to change, they just said there's no guarantees. But those are the two factors for ordering, and if the set isn't being modified, then those two factors are going to be stable from one iteration to the next.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good point. I can make the class consume just a plain Set and internally ensure that the class works as specified (combining and uncombining in reproducible order) (and actually, this is what I am doing right now, see http://svn.finmath.net/finmath%20lib/trunk/src/net/finmath/marketdata/calibration/IndependentParameterAggregation.java ).

Answer (score 3):

'HashSet.iterator does not return in any particular order' means that the elements returned by iterator are not sorted or ordered like in List or LinkedHashSet. But the HashSet.iterator will always return the elements in one and the same order while the HashSet is the same.

HashSet iterator is actually predictable, see this

```
    HashSet set = new HashSet();
    set.add(9);
    set.add(2);
    set.add(5);
    set.add(1);
    System.out.println(set);
```

I can foretell the output, it will be 1, 2, 5, 9. Because the elements kind of sorted by hashCode.

Comment: I do not need a predetermined ordering, but I do need that the iterator will always use the same ordering (as long as the set is not altered). LinkedHashSet has this property, but I assume I cannot check for it.

Comment: I agree that the HashSet.iterator API is not very clear. But I am 100% sure that the ordering will be the same for the same HashSet. It will go over its hashtable where elements are ordered by their hashCode, and the elements with the same hashCode are linked. You can test how it works.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to make the code safe or to point out the specific requirement (to people looking at the code) by a line of code instead of "implicitly" relying on this fact....

Comment: @Christian_Fries To remove ambiguity and provide clarity (which was your goal) you should still check SortedSet or List (as pointed out by @Moritz_Petersen) and use an appropriate implementation, as these interfaces guarantee the property, rather than relying on specific implementations. If not, make sure you comment you code well (explaining why you used a particular implementation)!